# Trying to figure out how to iterate through the posted data on an asp.net processing page

Tags: asp.net, forms

My form is dynamic, and submits what the user wants and i have a processing page just to handle the data:

```
<form id="imageForm" method="post" action="WebFormDesignImageProcessor.aspx" target="imageCollector">
  <input id="image61472" name="image[61472]" value="" src="file:\\C:\Users\william.francis\Downloads\errmergerd.jpg" type="file">
  <input id="image61474" name="image[61474]" value="" src="file:\\C:\Users\william.francis\Downloads\william_linkedin_photo.jpg" type="file">
  <input id="data[image61472]" name="image61472data" value="61472" type="hidden">
  <input id="data[image61474]" name="image61474data" value="61474" type="hidden">
</form>
```

The data is dynamic, and the forms can grow or shrink based on user input.  What i was wanting to do is to pair datasets together, and iterate through it in some fashion.

```
for( i = 0; i < $_POST['data[]'].length; i++){
   byte[] img = $_POST['image['.i.']'];
   string pk = $_POST['image'.i.'data];
   //then query
}
```

I understand the above sample was in a PHP pseudocode hybrid thing, but was looking for something in ASP.net.

**As a sidenote:  I can change the name design above to anything as long as the numbers are there... as that is what makes it unique.  That may make it a lot easier**

*edit:  I could give the names of the items as idData[] and imgData[], but when sending it to the server, i would not know which item references what.... as there isnt linking.... which is what the numbers are for.  This is a hurdle that in part, would help resolve the problem*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if you can quite do the same in .NET; however you could use linq:

```
var rq = HttpContext.Current.Request;
var keys = rq.Form.AllKeys.Where(i => i.StartsWith("data") == true);

foreach (var key in keys)
{
    //check key, and process accordingly
}
```

Something like that.  Note that the name is the identifier available in the form collection, not ID (pretty sure that is the case).

Comment: Not necessarily, but regex can't process a NameValueCollection in the same way LINQ can, that I know of.  You can put a regex expression inside a LINQ lambda statement, so you can use Regex.IsMatch instead of i.StartsWith, and get the best of both worlds.